# Newsletter in about us - why?

Tags: website-design, newsletter

I have in my hand a very weird project.

My company (ecommerce luxury men clothes) is thinking to re design our About Us but keeping the same copy, the typical copy content you can find in almost every single website, BUT at the same time they literally want:

OBJECTIVES:

b)     It leads more people to sign up to our newsletter (currently there is a sign up form at the bottom)

Ok I can add a new "write your email here" etc on the middle, top or in a pop up. However my question is why someone who goes to read the about us page will feel tempted to sign up for our newsletter? (I don't have any product there)

Does anyone can help understand why someone  could feel tempted to sign up  in the about us page?

Thanks

Comment: If the company people are leaders in their fields, maybe users will want to get some insights from them. For example, if the about us includes cool designers and fashion trendsetters, some people may be more interested to sign up to a newsletter, even though the clothes they saw up to this point didn't cause them to signup. Then again, it's quite farfetched, but if they ask you to do it... just do it. Nothing wrong will happen

Comment: Another guess: Investors want to stay abreast on any company news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people are interested, you can push them to next step by:

Providing a pop up after 3-5 sec. of scrolling down having the major information from your product/home/about page and a tempting content like privileged badge, latest news and rewards etc.

It is an acceptable implementation now a days.

Any screenshot/wireframe will help understanding your problem more by the way.